# TypeError: Cannot read property 'requestContent' of undefined

Tags: javascript, php

I have a php script that runs an executable file and then echoes it's result. The result is either '1' or blank so when the condition is true from the executable, the php script passes '1' to the calling javascript. Javascript needs to wait for the php script so it is in a async function (not that it should matter) so the line that should assign the value in the javascript file is:
**var cDor = await $.get("closeDoor.php");** as seen in the function below. I can run the php script on the command line and verify it's output as either 1 or nothing.
Because of the TypeError I am seeing in the console, I am obviously missing something in assigning the value in the calling script... Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
async function openCloseDoor(){
        if(document.getElementById("button1").value==" Close Coop Door "){
            document.getElementById("led1").classList.toggle('led-yellow');
            var cDor = await $.get("closeDoor.php");
            console.log(cCor);
            document.getElementById("button1").value=" Open Coop Door ";
            document.getElementById("led1").classList.toggle('led-off');}
        else if(document.getElementById("button1").value==" Open Coop Door "){
            document.getElementById("led1").classList.toggle('led-yellow');
            var oDor = await $.get("openDoor.php");
            console.log(oDor);
            document.getElementById("button1").value=" Close Coop Door ";
            document.getElementById("led1").classList.toggle('led-on');}
        location.reload(true);
    }
```

Comment: Please post the code of 'closeDoor.php'.

Comment: <?php
$file = fopen("/var/lib/cca/.field9.txt","r");
$var1 = fgets($file);
fclose($file);
exec("sudo closeW $var1 &", $out);
echo $out;
?>

Answer (score 0):

Needed to update the lookUpGuId operator to '==' from '=' (to be a comparison instead of an assignment), if anyone else runs into the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by changing the echo statement in the php file;
It was:

```
exec("sudo closeW $var1 &", $out);
echo $out;
```

Which seemed to echo an array... It now works with this small change:

```
exec("sudo closeW $var1 &", $out);
echo implode($out, PHP_EOL);
```

Now I wish I hadn't posted the questions but maybe it will be of help to someone else.